# meaning of: "Might be dated though!"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Actually, I got a reply from the author of a blog. It is the following

> I am glad it's of help to someone! Might be dated though!

However, I understand the meaning of the first part, that the *post* is able to help someone. But it is the next sentence, as per my raw guess, that the author is trying to say-

> "however it is old enough.."

I am uncertain whether the author wants to express the same or something else. Is my interpretation of the second sentence correct?

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of

> might be dated

Is that it might be old and no longer correct.  He is warning you that it may no longer be true because it is old. Dated meaning old.